# If $a, b, c, d> 0$ then I try to prove the following inequality..

Tags: inequality

If $a, b, c, d> 0$ then prove that $$a^2 b^2 c^2 + b^2 c^2 d^2 + a^2 b^2 d^2 + a^2 c^2 d^2 \geq ab^2 c^2 d + ab^2 cd^2 + a^2 bcd^2 + a^2bc^2d$$

I'm using AM GM relation but I'm not getting the answer, probably due to a conceptual mistake?

Comment: Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $\LaTeX$ syntax.

Comment: Im sorry im new and i dont know about this

Comment: No problem That's why I provided the link, so you may follow it and learn. Your questions will be better received if formatted

Comment: You have a mistake. the last term should be $a^2bc^2 d$ not $a^2bc^2 d^2$

Comment: Are you sure about the last term on the right side $a^2bc^2d^2$? Because this term is of grade $7$ which makes the inequality inhomogeneous

Comment: Yeah ive editted it. But how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may write $a^2b^2c^2 + b^2c^2d^2 + a^2b^2d^2 + a^2c^2d^2$ as

$$\frac{a^2b^2c^2 + b^2c^2d^2}{2} + \frac{b^2c^2d^2 + a^2b^2d^2}{2} + \frac{a^2b^2d^2 + a^2c^2d^2}{2} + \frac{a^2c^2d^2 + a^2b^2c^2}{2}$$

Apply the AM-GM inequality to each term to obtain the result.

Comment: Why do we take $b^2c^2d^2$ twice

Comment: Not just $b^2c^2d^2$, but the other three terms as well. We do this to pair every summand in your problem with every other summand. That way, you create four terms where each term has all four letters $a,b,c,d$ and two common factors, which is needed before we apply AM-GM.